# query to find no of empty columns from a table along with the name of the column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting an error when i am trying to use define command otherwise the code works fine please let me know how to use this code using define command.                       Define b_table='&Please enter the table name';

```
                    declare
                    v_count number;
                    cursor c2 is select Column_name 
                    from all_tab_columns
                     where table_name= '&b_table';

                    begin
                    for r1 in c2 loop
                    dbms_output.put_line(r1.column_name);
                    select count(r1.column_name) into v_count
                    from HR.'&b_table';
                    if v_count =0 then
                    dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
                    end if;
                    end loop;
                    end;
               old   5:  where table_name= '&b_table';
new   5:  where table_name= ' enter the table name';
old  11: from HR.'&b_table';
new  11: from HR.' enter the table name';
from HR.' enter the table name';
        *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 9:
PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: the first line which i missed it set serveroutput on;
Define b_table='&Please enter the table name';

Comment: please use edit to enter said line and also format the code

Comment: mind formatting it a little aamir?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query to find all columns in a table with no value in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031970/query-to-find-all-columns-in-a-table-with-no-value-in-it)

Comment: Duplicate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031970/query-to-find-all-columns-in-a-table-with-no-value-in-it. Also, it's not about mysql.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    SET serveroutput ON;
    DECLARE
      v_count      NUMBER;
      v_table_name VARCHAR2(200);
      CURSOR c2(v_table VARCHAR2)
      IS
        SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= v_table;
    BEGIN
      v_table_name := :table_name;
      FOR r1 IN c2(v_table_name)
      LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(r1.column_name);
        EXECUTE immediate('SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||')  FROM HR'||'.'||v_table_name) INTO v_count;
        IF v_count =0 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: not working saying bind_variable "table_name" not declared

Comment: @Optimuskck - EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'some dynamic query' into v_count; - that's the correct syntax for a single result.

Comment: Seem in your IDE bind variables are not prompting.either you have to declare it as a constant or change it to prompt-able  as  `v_table_name := &b_table`;

Comment: Btw, since this is duplicate :) I also noted that `r1.column_name` will not be evaluated in the string for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and it will error out. We need it ut of the string, so it can be evaluated.