# query to find all columns in a table with no value in it

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written this query for finding the total number of column which does not have a value in a table but its not working.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
        DECLARE
          v_count      NUMBER;
          v_table_name VARCHAR2(200);
          CURSOR c2
          IS
            SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= A;
        BEGIN
          FOR r1 IN c2
          LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(r1.column_name);
            EXECUTE immediate('SELECT COUNT(r1.column_name) INTO v_count FROM HR'||'.'||A);
            IF v_count =0 THEN
              dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not "compile" the `INTO v_count`. Instead do : `EXECUTE immediate('SELECT COUNT(r1.column_name) FROM HR'||'.'||'A') INTO v_count ;`. That's for starters after you execute this, output the value and then we'll discuss further.

Comment: r1.column_name invalid identifier throwing an error

Comment: `EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||') FROM HR'||'.'||'A' INTO v_count ;`. The command can't evaluate the r1.column_name, because it gets it as a string.

Comment: not throwing an error but its not printing anything also atleast it should print the frst line  dbms_output.put_line(r1.column_name); after loop

Comment: Next : `SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= 'A';` -> The change is table_name = 'A', instead of just A. May be even add the `HR.` schema name before that.

Comment: Also, this: `IF v_count =0 THEN dbms_output.put_line(v_count); END IF;` doesn't make any sense ... The general intent of the code, doesn't match the implementation - you would like to find the columns with no value, but I see no `WHERE ... col ... IS NOT NULL~ anywhere. Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the code you provided.

Comment: Awesome sir you are great its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to try this code. It works for me :)

```
SET serveroutput ON;
 DECLARE
  myOwner VARCHAR2(20):='HR';
  myTable VARCHAR2(25):='A';
  CURSOR c2
  IS
    SELECT column_name,
      avg_col_len
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = myTable
    AND owner        = myOwner;
BEGIN
  FOR r1 IN c2
  LOOP
    IF r1.AVG_COL_LEN =0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('column_name = '||r1.column_name);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: my code is working fine however it is hardcoded, i want to take input from user for the table name:

Comment: SET serveroutput ON;
        DECLARE
          v_count      NUMBER;
          CURSOR c2
          IS
            SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= 'A';
        BEGIN
          FOR r1 IN c2
          LOOP
            EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||') FROM HR'||'.'||'A' INTO v_count ;
            IF v_count =0 THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('Column'||' '||r1.column_name||' '||'is'||' '||v_count);
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
END;

Comment: Please help me so that i can take input from userSET serveroutput ON;
        DECLARE
          v_count      NUMBER;
          CURSOR c2
          IS
            SELECT Column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name= 'A';
        BEGIN
          FOR r1 IN c2
          LOOP
            EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT COUNT('||r1.column_name||') FROM HR'||'.'||'A' INTO v_count ;
            IF v_count =0 THEN
              dbms_output.put_line('Column'||' '||r1.column_name||' '||'is'||' '||v_count);
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
END;

Comment: Hi @aamirsaif,Is it a user input through a GUI? Can you clarify and detail your problem please?